# Any way to get category ID from a SearchResult object?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to get a category ID from a SearchResult object. I looked through the docs, didn't see anything that returns categoryID nor did I see anything that returns a YouTube.Videos.List object.

Here's my simple code. Just trying to loop and get category IDs for all.

```
for (SearchResult video:searchResultList)
            {
                //Get category ID of video
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a second call to get the category IDs, because (as you note) it's only included on the snippet of a videos.list object. I'm thinking the least painful way to do this would be to pass in the IDs as a comma-delimited string to the "ID" parameter of the videos.list call. It's a bit unfortunate, because it makes it difficult to do things such as, say, present categorically sorted search results to your user, but for now it's the only option.

Comment: Alright that's not too bad. I was worrying that it may be impossible.

Comment: And I can't upvote you. Not enough reputation. Good answer, though.

Comment: @martialdidit I know, but there someone may come up with something better. Also, I'm not sure this will work anymore.

Comment: I tried this line of code to check if rId (a video ID of type ResourceId) has a category id of "10" (I've read that "10" represents Music). My app is crashing, though and I'm not sure if this is the cause.

Comment: if (youtube.new Videos().list(rId.toString()).getVideoCategoryId() != "10")